# Longest prefix suffix

Tags: c++, stack

Given a string of character, find the length of longest proper prefix which is also a proper suffix.
Example:
S = abab then length will be 2 as prefix = 'ab' and suffix 'ab' is common .

Here is my code using stack . It is working for some cases and not for some . I am having hard time understanding why it is not working for some case . Can anyone explain what i am doing wrong ?

```
int main(){

long int T,i,j;

/* total test case */
cin>>T>>ws;

while(T--){
string str;

long int count = 0; 
getline(cin,str);

stack<char> charStack;

/** push all character till second last **/
for(i=0;i!=str.length()-1;i++){
    charStack.push(str[i]);
}
j = str.length()-1; 
while(!charStack.empty()){

    char ch = charStack.top();
    charStack.pop();
    if(ch==str[j]){

        count++;
        j--;
    }else {

        count = 0;
        j = str.length()-1;
    }




}   //inner while

cout<<count<<"\n";  


} //outer while





return 0;
}
```

It is failing for test case 
"khwkhpkhnkhwkhpkhtkhwkhpkhnkhwkhfkhwkhrkhwkhpkhnckhwkhpkhnkhwkhpkhtkhwkhpkhnkhdkhwkhpkhnkhwkhpkhtkhokhwkhpkhnkhwkhpkhtkhwkhpkhnkhwkhfkhwkhrkhwkhpkhnckhwkhpokhwkhpkhnkhwkhpkhtkhwkhpkhnkhwkhfkhwkhrkhwkhpkhnckhwkhpkhnkhwkhpkhtkhwkhpkhnkhdkhwkhpkhnkhwkhpkhtkhokhvkhwkhpkhnkhwkhpkhtkhwkhpkhnkhwkhfkhwkhrkhwkhpkgkhwkhpkhnkhwkhpkhtkhwkhpkhnkhwkhfkhwkhrkhwkhpkhnckhwkhpkhnkhwkhpkhtkhwkhpkhnkhdkhwkhpkhnkhwkhpkhtkhokhwkhpkhnkhwkhpkhtkhwkhpkhnkhwkhfkhwkhrkhwkhpkhnckhwkhpokhwkhpkhnkhwkhpkhtkhwkhpkhnkhwkhfkhwkhrkhwkhpkhnckhwkhpkhnkhwkhpkhtkhwkhpkhnkhdkhwkhpkhnkhwkhpkhtkhokhvkhwkhpkhnkhwkhpkhtkhwrkhwkhpkhnkhwkhpkhtkhwkhpkhnkhwkhfkhwkhrkhwkhpkhnckhwkhpkhnkhwkhpkhtkhwkhpkhnkhdkhwkhpkhnkhwkhpkhtkhokhwkhpkhnkhwkhpkhtkhwkhpkhnkhwkhfkhwkhrkhwkhpkhnckhwkhp"

The correct output is 155 while i am getting 55 .

Comment: You are comparing the characters from the top of the stack (the end of the string) to the characters from the end of the string (i.e. themselves), this is weird. What cases does it fail on exactly?

Comment: the last item in stack contain second last character of the string not the last character .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that while testing if the prefix (stack) matches the suffix, you remove the whole matching part from the stack. Sometimes that includes the tail of the truly longest prefix.

I added `std::cout << charStack.size() << '\n';` right after resetting `count`, and this is a relevant part of the output:

```
212
211
154
153
```

As you can see, you never tried to match with prefix length `155`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is MY KMP code:-

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;


int main(void){
    int t;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    while(t--){
        string s;
        cin>>s;
        int n = s.length();
        int arr[n];
        arr[0] = 0;
        int len = 0;
        for(int i = 1;i<n;){
            if(s[len]==s[i]){
                len++;
                arr[i++] = len;
            }
            else{
                if(len!=0){
                    len = arr[len-1];
                }
                else{
                    arr[i] = 0;
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }
        cout<<arr[n-1]<<endl;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Time complexity is O(N)